# WCF "endpoint not found" error (404 0 0)

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis

I am stuck by a very strange WCF problem on one of my asp.net website. The service returns "endpoint not found" error for only one type of service request. For instance:

It works fine for 
http://www.stackoverflow.com/main/UpdateService.svc/books/

but return "endpoint not found" error for
http://www.stackoverflow.com/main/UpdateService.svc/users/

What's more strange is if I build a debug version, and deploy it to a "Dev" asp.net website. Both 
http://www.stackoverflow.com/Dev/UpdateService.svc/books/
and
http://www.stackoverflow.com/Dev/UpdateService.svc/users/
work fine.

I have spent lots of time on the problem but still no luck with it. I looked the iis log files, the error code is "404 0 0 468".

Comment: This sounds like an IIS config issue. You'll need to show the config file of the service to get better help.